# Need To create MSI for SourceForge PDFCreator

Tags: windows-installer

I am using sourceforge PDFCreator source code & made some changes, now I want to create a installer of the same. What is the best solution suggested as I am not getting any clue/help from any forum on how to deploy the same.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code repository for PDFCreator has a configuration file for [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is a free Windows installation/setup program. (It's not exactly an MSI, but it works just fine--and in this case is already used for the default PDFCreator builds.)

So your fastest solution is to download and install InnoSetup (I'd recommend the [QuickStart Pack](http://www.jrsoftware.org/download.php/ispack-unicode.exe)), then look in the source code's "Setup" directory for a file called "[PDFCreator.iss](http://pdfcreator.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pdfcreator/trunk/Setup/PDFCreator.iss?view=markup)" which you can use to build the setup.exe with InnoSetup.

Comment: I neither see "Setup" directory nor a file "PDFCreator.iss" in the source code at: http://download.pdfforge.org/download/pdfcreator/list of version 1.9.3 or at: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/files/PDFCreator/ for version 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, Have tried the option told by you but ask for No. Of other components like IPDK, ManifistManager etc.